# CSS - White space under grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am still learning how to code CSS/HTML and very much a newbie at this. I created a simple 3 column 1 row grid. I am trying to figure out why there is a white space under my grid. It might not show on here via the snippet, but under the CMS I am working with, a huge white space under the grid keeps showing. I don't believe it's any of the other coding as it doesn't happen until I insert this particular code. Please see coding below.

```css
<style type="text/css">.cardcontainer {
    height: 125vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.card {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    gap: 0 50px;
    padding: 100px;
  
}
.card .card-item {
    position: relative;
}
.card img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 300px;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out all;
}
.card .card-details {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out all;
}
.card-details h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    margin: 2px 0;
}
.card-details p {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.card-item:hover .card-details {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 10px;
}
.card-item:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
@media(max-width:600px) {
    .card {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        gap: 0 10px;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="cardcontainer">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-item"><img alt="" src="/content/Banana.png" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" />
<div class="card-details">
<h1>Banana</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card-item"><img alt="" src="/content/Apple.png" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" />
<div class="card-details">
<h1>Apple</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card-item"><img alt="" src="/content/Oranges.png" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" />
<div class="card-details">
<h1>Oranges</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of **padding: 100px;** you have added in **.card** class

Comment: It's not. I added the padding in after but even if I move the padding, the white space under the grid still exists.